# Показывать одно и тоже изображение через несколько активностей

Tags: android

Я хочу показывать одно и тоже изображение на экране без прерываний пока запускаются 3 активности подряд: Загрузочная, Главная и затем Опция, и все это время пользователь видит только одну картинку.

Т.е. картинка должна скрыть загрузку нескольких активностей подряд. Обычно при загрузке приложения стартует Загрузочная, затем Главная, затем Опция. Как правило все заканчивается на Главной, и пока загружается Загрузочная, юзер видит картинку Приветствие (инфлэйтит Рилэйтив Лэйаут) несколько секунд, а затем уже интерфейс Главной. Очень редко приходится затем переходить на опцию, когда например была нажата в браузере ссылка на Опцию.
Но когда приходит пуш, мне необходимо переходить в Опцию сразу, но минуя Начальную и Главную активность я не запускаю несколько сервисов, не беру обновления с сервера, не выставляю необходимые переменные, а значит когда юзер из Опции попытается что-то сделать, то функционал будет ограничен.
Но и при нажатии на пуш показывать 3 различных интерфейса мне не нравится, поэтому решил спросить, можно ли на протяжении загрузки всех этих активностей чтобы висела некая картинка?

Comment: Переформулируйте пожалуйста вопрос и покажите, что уже сделано.

Comment: Вам нужно раскрыть свою задачу подробнее. Что это за картинка (как должна использоваться или что делать), почему она должна быть только одна, а не, например, одинаковая в разных активностях и проч. В текущем виде на вопрос нельзя дать полезный ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, отредактировал вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы получить одну картинку висящую все три активности подряд, я в Главной активности продублировал ключевые моменты из Загрузочной.
Пуш сразу запускает Главную, там я смотрю интент, если это пуш, то я показываю не основной layout, а дополнительный, с картинкой.
Далее, я запускаю вебсокет, логинюсь и запрашиваю сервер об обновлении данных касающихся именно этого пуша.
Получаю данные и загружаю активность Опция, где отображаю нужную информацию.

Дополнительно сделал: 
 - в onStop меняю в Главной активности отображаемый layout, чтобы при нажатии назад из Опции был показан нормальный вид Главной активности.
 - если в течении 10 сек не получаю ответа с сервера, тогда просто отображаю Опцию без новой инфы. Это не очень хорошо, но лучше, чем открыть Главную активность из которой полльзователь может не сразу найти нужную Опцию. А при запуске опции делается дополнительный запрос на сервер.